# avoid killing SSH in out-of-memory

Tags: ssh, priority, out-of-memory

When my server runs into out-of-memory, it usually kills several applications.
How can i prevent from killing SSH? Because usually, when this out-of-memory error happens, my SSH is broken like this:

```
I connect to ssh server.
Enter username
Enter password
```

and then i wait

i wait

and wait...

and waaaaaaaaaait..

and then:

```
Connection timed out.
```

**Is there any way to prevent this?**
How can i increase priority of process?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run the following command as root. You probably want to add this into an init script somewhere.

```
echo -17 > /proc/`pidof sshd`/oom_adj
```

**Update:**

To ensure that the main daemon process is the one being adjusted, you can use this command. The above will probably fail if you have any SSH sessions open, so not such a great choice :(

```
echo -17 > /proc/`cat /var/run/sshd.pid`/oom_adj
```

-17 is the current value for `OOM_DISABLE` in `/usr/include/linux/oom.h`. You can read more about the Linux OOM killer [here](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Comment: Thanks, but, "root@*****:~# pidof sshd" returns into
30330 24682 19633 19582 516 so i guess it will fail.

Comment: Yes, it would fail. You can replace with `pidof -s` to only return one pid. See my updated answer for better option.

Comment: i hope you will get more vote-ups :)

Comment: @Riki137 Thanks! Glad I could help :)

Comment: At which time should it be run on startup? >"You probably want to add this into an init script somewhere."

Comment: Is it OK to add that line straight into `/etc/init/ssh.conf`?

Comment: @SargeBorsch This isn't an SSH configuration option, so I'm not sure where you're suggesting to add it. This should work if you place it in `/etc/rc.local` for example. Or you could modify your SSH init script to do this.